# fastapi dependency injection

Tags: python, dependency-injection, fastapi

I want to know if there is a way to fail a dependency injection

ie. say i have a dependency to check if a user has correct authentication via cookie and decode jwt/cross check with db... now can i make sure it fails with a forbidden if i don't find them??

i expect to be able to return false in the function to stop the function but haven't seen it being used and can dependencies only be functions or even classes?
is there anyway i can create a class that checks for auth tokens and blocks the code if it fails or allow.i would like to use this similar to the way we have Formdata classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course. See e.g. [the authentication example in the FastAPI docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security/simple-oauth2/#code-to-get-the-username-and-password):  `get_current_active_user`, used as a dependency, raises an exception if it fails (paraphrased below):

```
async def get_current_user(...):
    ...

async def get_current_active_user(current_user: Depends(get_current_user)):
    if current_user.disabled:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Inactive user")
    return current_user

@app.get("/users/me")
async def read_users_me(
    current_user: Depends(get_current_active_user),
):
    return current_user
```

Comment: so i should raise an exception and it will stop the entire request?

Comment: Yes. An exception will travel up the chain and be returned back to the client. Execution will not continue in your endpoint/dependency/etc.